# NGINX authenticaion with reverse proxy does not work

Tags: nginx

I am trying to setup basic authentication on an nginx reverse proxy server.

I have an app that runs on port 9000 and use the nginx to reverse the proxy server to 80. That far everything works perfect.

If I try to add a basic authentication I get a `403: Forbbiden` error from nginx even if the user and password are correct.

The nginx config is below, I changed the `server_name` but everything else is the same

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name www.example.com example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
}
```

If I remove the following part everything works perfect but I have no auth

```
auth_basic "Restricted Content";
auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
```

The password file was created following the tutorial from NGINX Documentation [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/)

Can someone please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Simple Googling shows me [this link](https://christianfei.com/posts/setup-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-with-basic-auth-for-an-upstream/). According it, you should move `auth_basic` and `auth_basic_user_file` directives from location's section to server's section.

You could see working code in [this](https://gist.github.com/ATolkachev/e84741cd3ba2d042f6fa95b026bd4ea0) gist.

Comment: I tried this solution and it still does not work...

Comment: @Sabbin you could check my gist made from default nginx configuration.

Comment: What version of nginx do you have? maybe there is a difference between them. I doubt that but I cannot make this work even with their own tutorial... I have version 1.14.0 on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @Sabbin I have CentOS and `nginx/1.12.2`, updated to `nginx/1.14.2` and have same result.

Comment: I cannot see the difference then.. I followed the tutorial from NGINX documentation, there they have it inside the `location` also I found another tutorial https://community.openhab.org/t/using-nginx-reverse-proxy-authentication-and-https/14542  at the `Authentication with NGINX` section they also have posted that the `auth` should be placed under the `proxy_` fields...